# tfs web access - can't connect remotely

Tags: tfs

I have set up Team Foundation Server - Team Web Access SP1.

I can connect just fine from the internal network, but not from the Internet. Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eh , another question..

This is better suited for serverfault, but you need to diagnose the problem using a bottom up approach.

first , go through this checklist.

1) is your physical cabling working

2) is your routing to the server working ?

3) are the ports to the webserver working ? Check any firewall running ?

4) is the web server instance configured properly to let you access remotely ?

Comment: wow. officially i am an idiot. i cannot believe i didn't forward the ports to the server. sorry, have been extremely sleep deprived. and thank you, so so so so so so much!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Probably a question for Server Fault, but I suspect you have a firewall in between you and the Internet.  That is likely preventing you from accessing your server.

By the way, if you don't have a firewall, you should.